# Get Top 3 scores in each subjects from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have some problems in solving a SQL query.

There are two tables table1 and table2.

table1 has `studentId` (Primary Key) and `name`
table2 has `studentId`(FK), `subject`, `marks`

I am trying to write a query that will print subject wise the top 3 scorers along with the marks that they scored.

In Oracle11g I can easily do it with the Partition function. How to do the same in MySQL?

**Edit**:
I have created the table and input the values:

`CREATE TABLE table1
      (
        rollno int NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
      );`

`CREATE TABLE table2
     (
        rollno int  not null,
        subject varchar(60) not null,
        marks int not null,
        foreign key (rollno) references table1(rollno)
     );`

```
insert into table1 values(32,"john");
insert into table1 values(33,"amber");
insert into table1 values(34,"meher");
insert into table1 values(35,"lucy");
insert into table1 values(36,"philips");`

insert into table2 values(32,"maths",82);
insert into table2 values(32,"english",28);
insert into table2 values(32,"science",46);
insert into table2 values(33,"maths",67);
insert into table2 values(33,"english",89);
insert into table2 values(33,"science",72);
insert into table2 values(34,"maths",83);
insert into table2 values(34,"english",65);
insert into table2 values(34,"science",78);
insert into table2 values(35,"maths",98);
insert into table2 values(35,"english",87);
insert into table2 values(35,"science",81);
insert into table2 values(36,"maths",56);
insert into table2 values(36,"english",67);
insert into table2 values(36,"science",43);`
```

I am using the below code:

`select *
       from
           (   Select t1.name, t2.subject as su, t2.marks
               from table1 t1
               inner join table2 t2 on t1.rollno=t2.rollno
               order by t2.marks
           )t

       order by su, marks desc;`

But this code prints all students list subject wise . I am facing problem in limiting into top 3

Comment: Please provide some sample table data and expected output

Comment: Please include the query and the complete error message. Usually MySQL-Errors (especially "syntax errors") give you a pretty good hint what might be wrong with your query.

Comment: This link look something like what I think you are after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204889/rank-over-partition-by-in-mysql