# Select top 10 rows per group on a given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id int primary key
user_id int, 
activity_date date, 
activity_type int, 
activity_value float
```

uniq key on (user_id, activity_date, activity_type)

I would like to get top 10 rows ordered by `activity_value` from each `activity_type` on a given date (`activity_date`), say today or yesterday.

I tried the self join variant but not getting the correct results. Here is what I tried.

```
select 
  a.user_id, a.activity_date, a.activity_type, a.activity_value
from 
  my_table a
left join 
  my_table b on a.activity_type = b.activity_type and a.id < b.id
where 
  a.activity_date = curdate()
group by 
  a.id
having 
  count(*) < 10
order by 
  a.activity_value desc;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d30332/3

Can someone help me correct this query?

Comment: In T-SQL you can do a rank over partition for activity_type but I don't know what's the equivalent in MySQL.

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: @derloopkat as I know there is no equivalent in MySQL )

Comment: try `a.id <= b.id`

Comment: @VitaliiMuzalevskyi, something similar can be done but it's not straight forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204889/rank-over-partition-by-in-mysql

Comment: @RadimBača My current solution return only one top row from each group. tried a.id <= b.id but the result is still same.

Comment: @derloopkat I've underestimated MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you are almost there I guess you just miss the `b.activity_date = curdate()` condition. Also I think the `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary.

```
select a.*
from my_table a
join my_table b on a.activity_type = b.activity_type and 
                   a.activity_value <= b.activity_value
where a.activity_date = curdate() and b.activity_date = curdate()
group by a.id
having count(*) <= 10
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/052017/21)

Comment: This won't work. It returns rows correctly but not top rows order by activity_value. SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d30332/1

Comment: @Nagarjun try it now

Comment: That works great except the last result is always missing. For example, if you change the count(*) <=2 to <=3, I still see two rows per category even through there are 3 rows in the sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Nagarjun they are in different date, try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/222b0c/1