# getting distinct values in groups starting from one particular date mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

My scenario is like below.

```
id     email                    created_at
1     test1@gmail.com           2018-01-01
2     test1@gmail.com           2018-01-01
3     test2@gmail.com           2018-01-01
4     test3@gmail.com           2018-01-01
5     test4@gmail.com           2018-01-02
6     test1@gmail.com           2018-01-02
7     test1@gmail.com           2018-01-02
8     test5@gmail.com           2018-01-03
9     test4@gmail.com           2018-01-03
```

I want to get distinct email values on each day that are not exist in previous dates. If I group by date I will get results like below.

```
select count(distinct email) as count, created_at from test_table group by created_at

count     created_at
3         2018-01-01
2         2018-01-02
2         2018-01-03
```

But I need result like below

```
count     created_at
3         2018-01-01
1         2018-01-02
1         2018-01-03
```

Please provide solution to above.

Comment: If less typing is your thing, how about http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a6526/11

Comment: @strawberry Thanks it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you replicate `rank() over()` logic describes in this post:
[Rank() over Partition by in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204889/rank-over-partition-by-in-mysql)

I have tested this on my side and it worked. See fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a6526/10/0

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `email` varchar(100),
  `created_at` varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO `table` (`email`, `created_at`) VALUES
  ('test1@gmail.com', '2018-01-01'),
  ('test1@gmail.com', '2018-01-01'),
  ('test2@gmail.com', '2018-01-01'),
  ('test3@gmail.com', '2018-01-01'),
  ('test4@gmail.com', '2018-01-02'),
  ('test1@gmail.com', '2018-01-02'),
  ('test1@gmail.com', '2018-01-02'),
  ('test5@gmail.com', '2018-01-03'),
  ('test4@gmail.com', '2018-01-03')
;

select count(distinct a.email),
a.created_at
from (
    select email,
    created_at,
    case
        when email=@last
        then @curRank:=@curRank+1
        else @curRank:=0
    end as rank,
    @last:=email
    from `table`,
    (select @curRank:=0, @last:='') a
    order by email, created_at
) a
where a.rank=0
group by a.created_at
```

Comment: I haven't tested it because I don't have a mySQL database at hand at the moment but yes it should work out of the box. I'll update my answer if it does not work.

Comment: I confirm it does not work as is. The `rank()` function does not exist in MySQL

Comment: @SatyanarayanaSwamy I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works?

Comment: still iam getting the same result it is not eliminating duplicates from previuos dates

Comment: @Satyanarayanaswamy, I've updated the query above, it worked on my side. Can you try it?

Comment: @alexis it is giving error on my side. can you please create a sql fiddle for it.thanks.

Comment: @Satyanarayanaswamy what about now? (cf. updates above)

Comment: @Satyanarayanaswamy please consider marking this question as solved if it solved your issue. Thanks